# Pager with EntityQuery

Tags: database, paging

how can I make a pager with the pager class? I could not find anywhere how to do this with the EntityQuery class. I have a `pager(10)` that displays the last 10 items. I want to make a pager with numbers like
< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 >.

This is the code I have now:

```
class NewsArchive extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    // Query for newest articles and return max 3 results.
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $news = $query->condition('type', 'news')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->sort('created', 'DESC')
      ->pager(10)
      ->execute();

    // LoadMultiple News in $nodes variable
    $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($news);

    $path = base_path();

    // Return $nodes variable with name items to the module.
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'mytheme_news_archive',
      '#items' => $nodes,
      '#path'  => $path,
    );

  }
}
```

I have read somewhere that this was possible with the following code:

```
      $build['pager'] = [
        '#type' => 'pager',
      ];
```

How does this build pager (render) fit into my code? Can someone show me how to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the pager to the build array in which you return the results:

```
  return [
    'results' => [
      '#theme' => 'mytheme_news_archive',
      '#items' => $nodes,
      '#path'  => $path,
    ],
    'pager' => [
      '#type' => 'pager',
    ],
  ];
```

Or extend the theme with a variable `#pager` if you want to theme this in one place:

```
  return [
    'results' => [
      '#theme' => 'mytheme_news_archive',
      '#items' => $nodes,
      '#path'  => $path,
      '#pager' => [
        '#type' => 'pager',
      ],
    ],
  ];
```

Then you can print the pager in twig:

```
{{ pager }}
```

Comment: And how would I be able to print this in my twig / check the amount of pages etc.?

Comment: you don't have print this, drupal renders all elements it finds in the render array

Comment: I've added an example for the second option

Comment: Thank you for your respone, very helpful. The styling is done by a form or something I guess?

Comment: no, the pager uses links with a query string, you can style the pager in `pager.html.twig`

Comment: How does it know how many items are in the pager? Is it based on the number of elements in 'items'?

Comment: @4k4 Can We make it ajax pager? your reply saved my day